# Validating Rest Controller URL in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am adding a new record in the Postman using the URI `localhost:8080//insurance/service/add`.
Requirement - I want the application to throw an error in JSON mentioning an error code and customized message if any non-whitespace characters is after the URI. For example, if I want to add a record by using the URI such as `localhost:8080//insurance/service/add?` or `localhost:8080//insurance/service/add*` or anything like that, it should throw an error in JSON mentioning the error code and message. How should I proceed?

PS - new with spring boot.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("insurance/service")
public class InsuranceController{

@Autowired
Insurance_Service service;

// Create New Insurance
@PostMapping(path="/add", produces = "application/json")
public String addInsurance(@RequestBody (required=false) Insurance insurance ) {
  if(insurance==null)
  throw new MissingQueryParam();
this.service.addInsurances(insurance);
return "Insurance added successfully!!!";

 }
}
```

Comment: Your path should be **"/add"** . Why is it "/add/**" ? Is there any specific reason to that ?

Comment: Sorry Nakul. My bad. It should've been "/add". Rectified it

Comment: "?" at the end of url defines params. All other non-white space characters will throw error, which can be handelled.

Comment: "/" and ";" at the end are not throwing any error. But the requirement is that if we add anything (any non white space character) after "/add", it will throw an error.

Comment: Can you please share the request and response screenshots or data ?? Because I'm getting expected error when trying to add ";" or such characters at the end of url. ----->
Reponse message : **The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String \";\"**

Answer (score 0):

You can use @RestControllerAdvice or @ControllerAdvice to properly handle exceptions with http status.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class WebRestControllerAdvice {
  
  @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  public ResponseMsg handleNotFoundException(Throwable ex) {
    ResponseMsg responseMsg = new ResponseMsg(ex.getMessage());
    return responseMsg;
  }
}
```

ResponseMsg is coustomised Class to generate customised error response.
In this class you can handle any exception (customized too)